# Docker FROM UBUNTU

Tags: 16.04, docker

I've been trying to use `docker run` to launch a previously pulled Tensorflow image.

Once I've done that, is there a way to use `run` along with a tag to include all of my apt packages?

I tried using:

```
docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --privileged -it --env="DISPLAY" --env="PATH" --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/matthew -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb --network="host" tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter bash
```

I also tried `--env=$PATH`

This doesn't seem to work to include the apt packages.

I suppose the alternative is to use Docker From:Ubuntu as a parent image?

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: just to clarify, you wan to run apt command inside the container from the system?

Comment: I just want to be able to use apt packages inside the container such as gedit or nano, etc.

Comment: *All of TensorFlow's images are based on Ubuntu 16.04*, so you should be able to use `apt` inside the image. You should create your own `Dockerfile` with `FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter` and `RUN apt update && apt install ....`

Comment: I just did not want to install a second copy of apt packages. Was trying to find an alternative. I don't have unlimited storage. :)

Comment: Have you tried instead of only `bash`. you can use `apt update && apt install .... && bash`,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add additional packages in a docker image, you create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get install <whatever>
```

(it is recommended to install as much as you can in one call to `RUN apt-get install`, in other words, avoid using one `apt-get` per package)

You then create a new image using

```
docker build -t ubuntu-improved .
```

(`.` means "using the current directory as the source", `Dockerfile` is a reserved name for the container descriptions file, if you use another name, see the `-f` option). You can then run your image with

```
docker run ubuntu-improved
```

However, you normally don't need to install X and editors in the container (not even sure that X will run...). If you need to edit files used by the container, you use a bind-mount to share the file between host and container:

```
docker run -v /file/on/host:/file/in/container ubuntu-improved
```

Then you edit `/file/on/host` with your usual tools. The file can also be a directory.

Comment: also you can tag your own created imange docker build -t ubuntu-improved:tag